# How to make a Xul browser with no background?

Tags: transparency, xul

I want to render an animation in javascript in a html file. But I don't want my browser component to show the white background. Is there a way to make the background fully transparent?

Comment: would this be to show the desktop?

Comment: @Phill_Pafford actually to show any component behind it, maybe the Xul desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experience with xul, looks like it' not possible to make a browser with no background in a high level programming, maybe with some modifications on the low level code.